# ListView_GetNextItem(LVNI_VISIBLEONLY) not working

Tags: c, windows, winapi, win32gui

I need to process all of the items in a ListView (in report mode) that are visible to the user.  While debugging, I tried this:

```
int  item;
HWND hlist;

for( item = ListView_GetNextItem( hlist, -1, LVNI_VISIBLEONLY );
     item >= 0;
     item = ListView_GetNextItem( hlist, item, LVNI_VISIBLEONLY ) )
{
   if( ListView_IsItemVisible( hlist, item ) )
   {
      OutputDebugString("DEBUG:  Found a visible item!\n");
   }
}
```

According to the documentation, the GetNextItem loop should provide all of the items that are VISIBLE (in Vista or later and I'm on Win7).  However, my debug shows that it actually provides **ALL** items in the ListView.

So I added the redundant test of IsItemVisible, which is documented to return TRUE when the specified item is VISIBLE. Unfortunately, it returns FALSE for every single item found in the for() loop.

Obviously I'm missing something critical (and possibly obvious) here, but I'm at a total loss as to what it could be.  Oh, FWIW I'm testing under Windows 7 Professional x64, and my build target is WINVER 0x0601 (_WIN32_WINNT is also 0x0601).

Any ideas what I'm missing?

[update]

I've found a work-around (see below) but I'd still love to know why neither of the visible-related functions is working (for me).

For anyone interested, here's how I'm working around the problem:

```
   LVITEM         lvi;
   HWND           hlist = GetDlgItem( hwnd, LST_ALARMS );
   int            item;
   RECT           rcList;
   RECT           rcItem;
   RECT           rcHead;

   GetClientRect( hlist, &rcList );
   // Remove the header space from the visible item area
   GetClientRect( ListView_GetHeader(hlist), &rcHead );
   rcList.top += (rcHead.bottom - rcHead.top);

   memset( &lvi, 0, sizeof(lvi) );

   for( item = ListView_GetNextItem( hlist, -1, LVNI_ALL );
        item >= 0;
        item = ListView_GetNextItem( hlist, item, LVNI_ALL ) )
   {
      if( ListView_GetItemRect( hlist, item, &rcItem, LVIR_BOUNDS )
         && (rcList.top <= rcItem.top)
         && (rcItem.bottom <= rcList.bottom) )
      {  // This item is COMPLETELY visible 
         // -- partially visible items are NOT included.
         lvi.mask  = LVIF_PARAM;
         lvi.iItem = item;
         ListView_GetItem( hlist, &lvi );
         // do stuff with item
      }
   }
```

This is working exactly as I hoped the things at the beginning of this message would do.  I'd prefer the easier readability of the visibility functions, but since I need it to actually work, I'm stuck comparing rectangles.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but are you sure `hlist` is actually valid? Do any other messages work? E.g. what does `ListView_GetItemCount(hlist);` return?

Comment: Yes, hlist is valid.  Before I noticed the functions not working, I was calling ListView_GetItem( hlist, item, &lvi ) to get the item's lparam and that works just fine.

Comment: You can streamline your workaround by starting with the top-most visible item (`ListView_GetTopIndex`). And then break from the loop as soon as the list item isn't completely visible.

Comment: I have the early break in the real code, but thanks for the tip about GetTopIndex!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of visibility used by `LVNI_VISIBLEONLY` is not "visible on screen right now". It is "has not been removed from view". (An object becomes removed from view if it belongs to a group that has been collapsed.) So it is expected that `LVNI_VISIBLEONLY` returns all elements if you are not using collapsible grouping.

In other words, "visible" means "not hidden", not "on screen". This is the same sense used by `IsWindowVisible` and `TVNI_NEXTVISIBLE` and other APIs.

Comment: Interesting.  That seems to make sense.  Is there any chance that you can provide a reference to Microsoft's documentation that confirms what you're saying?  Also, do you think that the same holds true for the ListView_IsItemVisible() macro (or message) -- which returns FALSE for EVERY SINGLE ITEM in my ListView in ReportMode.  (Also, FWIW, no one on Microsoft's own forums has figured this out (if true) and they're down to debugging sample code!)

Comment: @SteveValliere I will have the documentation clarified.

Comment: thanks, every little bit helps when one is depending on accurate and complete documentation in order to get a job done!  (I keep trying to add /'at'RaymondChen/ to my comments, but the site strips it out, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

There's a curious note at the bottom of the LVM_GETNEXTITEM explanation that may explain your problem:

> Remarks
>
> Note that the following flags, **for use only with Windows Vista**, are
>   mutually exclusive of any other flags in use: LVNI_VISIBLEONLY,
>   LVNI_SAMEGROUPONLY, LVNI_VISIBLEORDER, LVNI_DIRECTIONMASK, and
>   LVNI_STATEMASK.

Comment: Since only one of those flags is being used I don't think it does.

Comment: I was concerned about that, too, but I found that at other points in the documentation is says "for use only with Windows Vista or later" instead.  Win7 would be "later", right?  ;-)

Comment: That's the thing.  You can never tell for sure with Microsoft documentation.